# socket client-server python on different machines

Tags: python

hello everyone i am creating a simple client-server program that sends messages from one client to another via the server, the fact is that on the same machine the program runs fine and fills the problem and when the client and server run on machines different, the client just can't connect to the server I don't know if it's a proxy configuration or port forwarding problem. for safety I removed my ip from the variable, during execution I entered the ip that gave me the ipconfig command from the cmd

server code:

```
import threading
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip=""
port=55556
s.bind((ip, port))
s.listen()

clients=[]
nicknames=[]

def send_to_all(messaggio): #invia "messaggio a tutti i clients nella lista"
    for client in clients:
        client.send(messaggio)

def receive_messaggio(client):#riceve il messaggio dal client e lo invia a send_to_all #inserire try and exept
    while True:
        try:
            messaggio=client.recv(1024)
            print(messaggio.decode("utf-8"))#is str composto da nickname e messaggio inviati direttamente dal clients

        except:
            index=clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname=nicknames[index]
            print(f"{nickname} ha abbandonato la chat")
            send_to_all(f"{nickname} ha abbandonato la chat".encode("utf-8"))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

        if messaggio.decode("utf-8").find("\\esc")!=-1:
            index=clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname=nicknames[index]
            print(f"{nickname} ha abbandonato la chat")
            send_to_all(f"{nickname} ha abbandonato la chat".encode("utf-8"))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break


        send_to_all(messaggio)#.decode

def runtime():
    while True:
        client, indirizzo_client=s.accept()

        client.send("NICK".encode("utf-8"))
        nickname=client.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f"{str(indirizzo_client)} si è connesso al server con il nome: {nickname}")

        client.send("connessione al server avvenuta con successo".encode("utf-8"))
        send_to_all(f"{nickname} e entrato nella chat || partecipanti: {len(nicknames)}\n".encode("utf-8"))

        thread=threading.Thread(target=receive_messaggio, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

print("server avviato, in attesa di client\n")
runtime()
```

client code:

```
import threading
import socket

nickname=input("nickname: ")
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip=""
port=55556
s.connect((ip, port))

def ricezione():
    while True:
        message=s.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
        if message=="NICK":
            s.send(nickname.encode("utf-8"))
        else:
            print(message)

def scrittura():
    while True:
        message=f'{nickname}: {input("")}'
        s.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
        if message.find("\esc")!=-1:
            s.close()
            exit()

threadR=threading.Thread(target=ricezione)
threadR.start()

threadW=threading.Thread(target=scrittura)
threadW.start()
```

Comment: start at the beginning - can you ping the server computer from the client computer? if not, you probably have network issues. If ping works, run the program on the server and try telnet to the server on that port. If that fails, its a reasonable bet that a firewall is blocking the port.

Comment: thanks for the help, if i try to use my mobile as a server and my computer as a client it works but if i do the opposite the terminal freezes, i tried to ping both devices and that's ok